# Why do we use '/' sign as a representation of 'or'?

Tags: etymology, punctuation

Imagine that you want to write something about colors and you know that **red or blue** would work in that context. How do you write that? I've seen these styles:

1. Red or blue
2. Red, or blue
3. Red/blue

Why is this sign used as a substitute for 'or'? I mean, in computer engineering, '|' represents 'or' and in mathematics, 'V' represents 'or'. Is there any reason why this symbol is chosen?

PS: The same case is true about '&' sign (ampersand).

Comment: Mathematics and programming languages are not English, so they don't have to follow English rules or conventions, and English doesn't need to follow theirs either. A lot of computer symbols were chosen because those were the symbols available on the QWERTY keyboard.

Answer (score 4):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slash_%28punctuation%29), one reason may be:

> The slash is also sometimes used to denote (often mutually exclusive) alternatives, such as in male/female.

So it's easy to see why that could be expanded, as a shorthand for *or* in the case of non-mutually exclusive items.

Answer (score 1):

I will just add that the vertical bar | is used in many programming languages to represent *or* because of convention. The symbol has many uses in math (absolute value, set-builder notation, etc), but to the best of my knowledge is not used for *or*.

The use of *V* for *or* comes from first-order logic. It's not actually the letter V, but that is often used in place of the union symbol. The union of A and B = A or B.

Finally the ampersand. This symbol is shorthand for *et*, which means *and* in Latin. In old books many printers use *&c* instead of *etc*, which, of course, stands for the the Latin phrase *et cetera*.

Answer (score 0):

The slash divides two things.  eg. red/blue you are drawing a line, cutting between the two words like a sword cut.

But red-blue is joining the two words, like a rope tied between them.

The symbols in maths and computers are more varied they are a combination of what typewriter symbols were available on early keyboards and what had already been used in previous systems.

Comment: Re  “red-blue is joining the two words, like a rope tied between them”, just as well as that one might interpret  *red-blue* as red minus blue, which is not a joining.